# Did Protestants prefer "children" as opposed to "sons" of God in their translations of Matthew 5:9?

Tags: matthew, translation-philosophy

In [the Wikipedia page for Matthew 5:9](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matthew_5:9) it says this about protestants preferring the translation of children rather than sons. (Huios) As there is no citation for this point, can someone point to any other authority that can confirm this paragraph below:

> Martin Luther and other early Protestant translators of the Bible preferred the translation "children of God," because they wanted to avoid any confusion as to whether Jesus was the only Son of God. "Sons of God" is, however, the more accurate translation and is used by most modern Bible translations. In several places the Gospel makes clear that the population in general can be called sons of God and Jesus frequently refers to God as "our Father" or "your Father."

Comment: you should try the original que on Christianity SE.

Comment: Hi @bunny7, it looks like you became frustrated in relation to this question, but I can't really tell what happened. Please do feel free to raise a flag or reach out if you believe you are experiencing unkind behaviour on the site.

Comment: Hello thank you for your reply. At the time I posted this I was getting many replies that were quite aggressive. I originally asked why Protestant versions of the Bible translated Huios as children instead of sons which is what it should be generally. I was attacked because my question seemed to cause an uproar because they thought my question was suggesting women couldn’t be peacemakers. The Bronze Age to Roman period was a very patriarchal time and most women wouldn’t be peacemakers and my question was historically aligned. I eventually found out that…..

Comment: ……The original Protestant Luther Bible was based on the Latin Vulgate and Jerome universally translated sons/children as Filii without the nuance of the original Greek that distinguished Huios/teknon. I found this out through commentaries and an analysis of the Latin in relation to the Greek. I tried to defend myself but they kept deleting and downvoting my posts. I was treated in a very hostile manner here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typically, the word for children is translated from 'tekna'. Huios is usually translates as sons. But this is not always the case.

Comment: Hi thanks for your response! Yes I’ve been studying Greek and I concur with that 100%. However for my paper I need to confirm that Protestant translators preferred to translate Huios as children rather than sons. I’m looking for either a primary source to confirm that or secondary author. Thanks!

Comment: For other references you should check Ellicott or Bengel's Gnomen or the BAGD

Comment: In all the Textus Receptus versions I reviewed all had children instead of sons. In all the ancient manuscript translations I checked, like the Vulgate had sons. I’m wondering if there was a Protestant bias in using children instead of sons. In the King James Bible I noticed in numerous places that when not referring to Jesus they used children in place of sons to not confuse the son of God and other sons of God. My paper is arguing against the KJV on this particular verse.

Comment: That could be a possibility but this would only be speculating as to the motives of the translators.

Comment: Yes it would be speculation. However the wiki entry seems quite certain so I’m wondering if there are any sources to back up the assertion.

Comment: I would be very careful about trusting any information found on any wiki site. Most professors will not accept wiki sites as a legitimate source.

Comment: Yes I agree that’s why I’m looking to back this up elsewhere. This paper is going to be published online and not graded. Although there’s no citation it seems plausible that the reformation may have biased the translation of that word so that’s why I’m looking for proof.

Comment: Have you examined the TR MSS to see if there are any variances on the verse?

Comment: Yes I have. In every Greek text I’ve seen it’s always been Huios and not Teknon or any other variant.

Comment: I have never found any MSS that has s a variant here. Personally, I can think of no legitimate reason for translating υἱοὶ as children.

Comment: Yeah I agree! I just wish I could find a source explaining why they chose that translation when they knew it was false.

Comment: Bunny, why did you accept this as right answer when it doesn't answer your q?

Answer (score 4):

There is an old aphorism that "Men do not own their own gender".  By this is meant that a feminine word (for a person) is always feminine; but a masculine word often includes both sexes.

One can see this in many places.  Here are some examples:

- Jesus title of "Son of Man" means son of humanity, ie, both sexes included.
- Jesus said in Mark 1:27, 28, "“The Sabbath was made for **man**, not man for the Sabbath. Therefore, the Son of Man is Lord even of the Sabbath.”  Here the highlighted "man" clearly means "mankind", is, humanity.
- Rom 8:14 - For all who are led by the Spirit of God are **sons** of God.  Again, υἱοί here means both sexes.
- Acts 13:26 - “**Brothers, sons** of the family of Abraham, and those among you who fear God, to us has been sent the message of this salvation.  Again, both "brothers" and "sons" includes both sexes.
- Mark 13:28 - Truly I tell you, the **sons** of men will be forgiven all sins and blasphemies, as many as they utter.  Again, this represents both sexes.

Indeed, many such examples could be quotes such as: Eph 3:5, Matt 5:9, Luke 20:36, Rom 8:19, 9:26, Gal 4:6, etc.

On the specific subject of "peacemakers" in Matt 5:9, this gaian, can apply to botn sexes as displayed several times in the Bible:

- Prov 24:17, 18 - Do not gloat when your enemy falls, and do not let your heart rejoice when he stumbles, or the LORD will see and disapprove, and turn His **wrath away from him**.
- Prov 15:1 - A gentle answer **turns away wrath**, but a harsh word stirs up anger.
- Jer 18:20 - Should good be repaid with evil? Yet they have dug a pit for me. Remember how I stood before You to speak good on their behalf, to **turn Your wrath from them**.
- Prov 29:8 - Mockers inflame a city, but the wise **turn away anger**.

We have some wonderful stories of wise women who were peacemakers such as:

- 2 Sam 14:24 - wise woman from Tekoa
- 2 Sam 20:15-23 - the wise woman of Abel
- 1 Sam 25:3 - Abigail was wise enough to prevent bloodshed

Thus, by explicit teaching and example, peacemakers can be of both sexes.

Comment: The linguistics terminology would be to say that the feminine (and neuter) genders are more [marked](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markedness), while the masculine gender is unmarked. There are situations where grammatical genders/word-classes can even be shown as a Venn diagram, so that the non-masculine genders aren't entirely distinct, but just categories which in some situations have distinct forms, and in others take the masculine forms. In Biblical Greek you can see this when there's no distinct feminine form: 3rd declension case endings, interrogative pronouns, and some adjectives.

Comment: @curiousdannii - this is all true but I did not want to over-complicate the story beyond what those unfamiliar with such subtleties could grasp.

Comment: If it was Tekno then I think it would be hard to argue against the reading of children but Huios is certainly debatable and leans more toward sons. Even if sons was to be applied to both genders (And based on all the evidence it shouldn’t), it still should be translated as sons with the general understanding that it applies to both genders. It would be like replacing the expression “mankind” with “humankind” . If the record had sons it should remain transmitted that way because anything else is an inference.

Answer (score 2):

With the plural, such as υἱοὶ θεοῦ, as opposed to the singular, the translation *sons* is not so clear cut.  For example (Gal. 3:26-28) ends up with male and female (ἄρσεν καὶ θῆλυ) sons of God (υἱοὶ θεοῦ).

26 Πάντες γὰρ **υἱοὶ** θεοῦ ἐστε διὰ °τῆς πίστεως ⸂ἐν Χριστῷ Ἰησοῦ⸃· 27 ὅσοι γὰρ εἰς Χριστὸν ἐβαπτίσθητε,* Χριστὸν ἐνεδύσασθε. 28 οὐκ ἔνι Ἰουδαῖος οὐδὲ Ἕλλην, οὐκ ἔνι δοῦλος οὐδὲ ἐλεύθερος, οὐκ ἔνι **ἄρσεν καὶ θῆλυ**· ⸀πάντες γὰρ ὑμεῖς ⸂εἷς ἐστε ἐν Χριστῷ⸃ Ἰησοῦ.*
(28th Edition, Gal. 3:26–28, NA28)

Neither is Catholic or Protestant so clear.  Here is a prominent Roman Catholic translation:

> 26 For through faith you are all **children** of God in Christ Jesus.
> 27  † For all of you who were baptized into Christ have clothed yourselves with Christ.
> 28 There is neither Jew nor Greek, there is neither slave nor free person, there is not **male and female**; for you are **all** one in Christ Jesus.
> --
> Confraternity of Christian Doctrine. Board of Trustees, Catholic Church. National Conference of Catholic Bishops, and United States Catholic Conference. Administrative Board. (1996). *The New American Bible: translated from the original languages with critical use of all the ancient sources and the revised New Testament* (Gal 3:26–28). Confraternity of Christian Doctrine.

Regardless of how one translates υἱοὶ in Gal. 3:26-28, Paul essentially indicated that there is no difference in the inheritance of Chrisian women from Christian men.  That is why Paul Used υἱοὶ θεοῦ instead of τέκνα θεοῦ.

And Matt 5:9 from the same translation:

```
  9 Blessed are the peacemakers, 
 for they will be called children of God.
            (Matt. 5:9, NAB)
```

Matt. 5:9 is not as clear as Gal. 3:26-28.  In Greek, Hebrew, and languages which designate gender in plural nouns and pronouns, when both men and women are involves and the language as no common form, the masculine plural is used.  In Matt. 5:9 there is no reason to believe that women cannot be peacemakers.